# What is the most time efficient way to guarantee at least one nanosecond has elapsed in Go? time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond) can take milliseconds

Tags: go, wait, sleep

I have two function calls that I would like to separate by at least a nanosecond. But I want the delay to be as small as possible.

The code below shows an empty for loop is much more efficient at this than using `time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond)`

Is there an even more efficient way to guarantee at least one nanosecond has elapsed?

```
func TimeWaster () {
    start := uint64(time.Now().UnixNano())
    stop := uint64(time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(time.Duration(stop-start))//0s
    //no nanoseconds pass

    start = uint64(time.Now().UnixNano())
    time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond)
    stop = uint64(time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(time.Duration(stop-start))//6.9482ms
    //much *much* more than one nanosecond passes

    start = uint64(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for uint64(time.Now().UnixNano()) == start {
        //intentionally empty loop
    }
    stop = uint64(time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(time.Duration(stop-start))//59.3µs
    //much quicker than time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond), but still much slower than 1 nanosecond
}
```

Comment: May I ask why would you care that a single nanosecond has passed?

Comment: I am using a package that I have no control over. This package defines uniqueness by the nanosecond. Sadly, I can and do call it within the same nanosecond. So, I only care because some package cares for reasons unrelated to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you're using strangely enforces uniqueness of values by time, so all you need to do is loop until the `time` package is no longer reporting the same value for the current nanosecond.  This doesn't happen after 1 nanosecond, in fact the resolution of the `UnixNano` is about 100 nanoseconds on my machine and only updates about every 0.5 milliseconds.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano())
    smallWait()
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano())
}

func smallWait() {
    for start := time.Now().UnixNano(); time.Now().UnixNano() == start; {}
}
```

The loop is pretty self-explanatory, just repeat until the `UnixNano()` is different

Comment: I am using a package that I do not control which defines uniqueness by the nanosecond. Sadly, I can and do call it twice within the same nanosecond. So, I only care because some package does for reasons unrelated to time.

Comment: Then your problem comes down not to waiting more than 1 nanosecond, but waiting until a time when the `time` package will no longer report that it is in the same nanosecond, which isn't the same thing.  In my tests, the `time.Now().UnixNano()` only updates every 0.5 milliseconds or so.  The only guaranteed way to do this is to just sleep for the minimum amount of time, or run a loop and keep checking to see if the value has changed yet.

Comment: This is what I have settled on for the time being.